# Could not find timers-1.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, passenger

Phusion Passenger throws the following error:

```
Could not find timers-1.1.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I'm really not sure what this timers-1.1.0 gem is, but I do have a gem called sidekiq and when I perused Gemfile.lock, I did notice that sidekiq depended on celluloic and celluloid depended on timers (My Gemfile includes sidekiq but not the other two):

```
sidekiq (2.13.0)
  celluloid (>= 0.14.1)

celluloid (0.14.1)
  timers (>= 1.0.0)
```

I have a production server that works fine, and now I deployed my first staging server (a different ip and git branch from production). The staging branch is IDENTICAL to the master branch on github.

It seems the staging server is missing the timers-1.1.0 that the production server has. That is what really confuses me. I am using RVM. And my capistrano task includes the following:

```
set :rvm_type, :system
before "deploy", "deploy:create_gemset"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Create the gemset"
  task :create_gemset do
    run "rvm #{rvm_ruby_string} --create"
  end

 desc "Install the bundle"
  task :bundle do
    run "bundle install --gemfile #{release_path}/Gemfile --without development test"
  end
end
```

So I assumed that when I did my first deploy of staging, it would create a gemset for staging server that mirrored the gemset of production server, and it would run bundle install to make sure that the new gemset on staging had all the gems of production server. But obviously this did not happen.

I compared the two servers:

production server:

```
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.17.3 (stable)

$ rvm list    
rvm rubies
=* ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ rvm info | grep gem
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake"
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global"
    gemset:       ""
```

staging server:

```
$ rvm -v    
rvm 1.21.2 (stable)

$ rvm list    
rvm rubies
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

   $ rvm info | grep gem
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rake"
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/myuser/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global"
    gemset:       ""

    $ rvm gemset list
    gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p429 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429)
    (default)
    global
    spree_ecommerce
    => MySite

    $ rvm gemdir
   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@MySite

    cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@MySite
    $ cd gems
    $ ls -l | grep timers                                    
    drwxrwsr-x  4 myuser rvm 4096 Jul 24  2013 timers-1.1.0

    rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p429 --default
    rvm-prompt
    Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
```

Note I also tried running bundle install on staging server as well.

One thing I did notice was Phusion Passenger. My production server default ruby version and the passenger configuration were identical:

```
$ rvm-prompt
ruby-1.9.3-p327

$ cat passenger.conf
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p327/ruby

$ cat passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/passenger-3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

But staging server were different:

```
$ rvm-prompt
ruby-1.9.3-p429

$ cat passenger.conf
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12

$ cat passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.12/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

Perhaps Passenger is looking at the wrong ruby and gemset on staging?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else has this issue, it was indeed phusion passenger at fault. It was using the wrong ruby version and ruby gems. The version of ruby/gems it was using did not have the timers gem installed in it. The solution was to change the apache configuration file to update passenger to use the right ruby/gems:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
$ sudo vim passenger.conf
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@MySite/gems/passenger-4.0.41
 PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429@MySite/ruby
</IfModule>

$ sudo vim passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@MySite/gems/passenger-4.0.41/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
$ sudo a2enmod passenger
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Also make sure the passenger gem is indeed installed in the version of ruby/gems you are using for your application.